# Why does this simple email script sends two emails every time

Tags: email, inotifywait

Why does this script send two emails instead of one?

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR="/path/to/directory"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" | while read 
NEWFILE
do
[  -z "${NEWFILE}" ] && : || MOVIE=$(find "$NEWFILE" -type f -not -name ".*" 
\( -iname "*.mkv" -o -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.avi" \) -exec basename {} 
\; | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//')
[  -z "${MOVIE}" ] && : || echo "Please don't reply to this 
automatically generated email message." | mail -s "$MOVIE is now on Plex!" 
"email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com"
done
```

Comment: tried replacing the two email addresses in the second last line with one?

Comment: @Syfer They are two separate emails.

Comment: Just confirming, it sends the same email twice to both the emails address?

Comment: @swapnilsm Correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
[  -z "${MOVIE}" ] && : || echo "Please don't reply to this
```

Note that `A && B || C` is not `if-then-else`. C may run when A is true.